# R plot raster with real colors

Tags: raster, r, rgdal

I'have a raster image from Scran25 IGN. In Qgis, it opens perfectly but in R (with rgdal or raster packages), I do not know how to keep the original colors like this exemple?

[image: IGN scan25 from Banyuls]

I have tried

```
library('rgdal')
library('raster')

scan25<-readGDAL("./Banyuls/MyCreate/etudehydoAOC/etudehydoAOC/Scan25/vrt_4communes.vrt")
communes<-readOGR(dsn = "./Banyuls//MyCreate/Surface_4communes/",layer = "4communesAOC")

scan25<-raster(scan25)
test<-aggregate(scan25,10,mean)

plot(communes)
plot(test,add=T)
```

And the result is 
[image: IGN scan25 import in R with bad colors]

Comment: Show some code! Use ?brick and ?plotRGB. We can only guess what your actual problem is

Comment: I have write some news thing... `scan25`, I believe, is a "one band" raster. I do not understand how the past has three band? Is it needed?

Comment: You are using the raster() function which is only intended for single band rasters. If you use stack() or brick() then your three RGB bands will be in the resulting raster class object. You will still need plotRGB to display the composite image.

Comment: We need to what raster source is referenced by thay VRT. It may be rgb or palette but no point in us guessing.

Comment: Could you post the content of   `scan25@legend@colortable`?

Comment: scan25@legend@colortable ? et voilà `[1] "#FFFFFF" "#FF00FF" "#0033FF" "#0080FF" "#B3D9FF" "#00FFFF" "#66FFFF" "#00FF00" "#66FF4C" "#55FF00" "#80FF40" "#D1FFBA" "#E0FFD1" "#FFFF00"`

Comment: @mdsumner this VRT is a collection of 4 GeoTiff

Comment: Use raster or brick on the file name, not via rgdal. If it is a palette  raster() and plot will work, if rgb then brick and plotRGB will work.

Comment: You are aggregating `scan25` and thus, if I am not mistaken, you are losing the association data/color.

Comment: @mdsumner you're right with readGDAL I lost the color association. So thank's @Pascal to ... with `raster()` and `plot()` it work !

Answer (score 2):

Very simple:

```
#load the raster as a stack so all channels are included
img_stack=stack(img_name)
#then plot it an RGB raster
plotRGB(img_stack)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use brick function in raster

```
library(raster)
r = raster::raster(fname)
s = raster::brick(r)
raster::plotRGB(s)
```